# Making a calendar - months starting on a Sunday gets first week trimmed off

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to make a calendar, but I'm facing a problem where months starting on a Sunday, gets their first week cut off. Everything else seems to work, like the number of days in a month, and the dates actually being correct:

```
        August 2021
MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
 02  03  04  05  06  07  08
 09  10  11  12  13  14  15
 16  17  18  19  20  21  22
 23  24  25  26  27  28  29
 30  31
```

This is my code so far:

```
DateTime displayMonth = new DateTime(2021, 8, 1); // This will be dynamic, ofc.
int firstDay = (int)displayMonth.DayOfWeek;
int cellCounter = 0;
int daysInMonth = (int)DateTime.DaysInMonth(displayMonth.Year, displayMonth.Month);
int weeksInMonth = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(firstDay + daysInMonth) / 7);
for (var w = 0; w <= weeksInMonth; w++)
{
    <div class="row">
        @for (var d = 0; d < 7; d++)
        {
            cellCounter++;
            <div class="col">
                @{
                    int day = 1 + cellCounter - firstDay;
                    if (day > 0 && day <= daysInMonth)
                    {
                        <h1>@day</h1>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Note, `displayMonth.DayOfWeek` will be 0 when Sunday (because that's what the US uses for the start of its week), but you _really_ want it to be day number 7 (or more aptly offset 6).

Comment: Move the cellCounter++; below the "coll" div as you increment the day before you actually use it and as @gunr2171 mentioned Sunday starts at a 0 day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

I already knew about the index values of `DayOfWeek` and Sunday being 0. What I didn't have, was a "conversion" to shift Monday to 0:

```
int firstDay = ((int)displayMonth.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;
```

This is the working code:

```
DateTime displayMonth = new DateTime(2021, 9, 1); 
int firstDay = ((int)displayMonth.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;
int cellCounter = 0;
int daysInMonth = (int)DateTime.DaysInMonth(displayMonth.Year, displayMonth.Month);
int weeksInMonth = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(firstDay + daysInMonth) / 7);
for (var w = 0; w <= weeksInMonth; w++)
{
    <div class="row">
        @for (var d = 0; d < 7; d++)
        {
            cellCounter++;
            <div class="col">
                @{
                    int day = cellCounter - firstDay;
                    if (day > 0 && day <= daysInMonth)
                    {
                        <h1>@day</h1>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```